# What is the name of this data normalization?

Tags: data-analysis

I have a two-dimensional array ($569\times30$ double) which should be normalized using this formula:

$x'_{ij} = \dfrac{x_{ij} - \overline\mu_j}{\overline\delta_j} $

What is the name of this normalization and how can I do that in Matlab?

Comment: Its another question, another formula. I post this in separated question to make answer simpler and give more reputations to who answers

Comment: Ah! I see that you changed the $h$ to a $\bar\delta_j$ while I was commenting (or perhaps I was simply seeing things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This transformation is called Z-score ([see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) wikipedia entry). It can be implemented easily in Matlab, just take a look on [zscore](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/zscore.html) function. Please notice, that the result depends on how you store your data (if samples are stored in the rows or in the columns).